# Older Brompton front brake cable

Tags: brakes, brompton

I needed to replace the front brake cable on my old brompton, so (after a bit of searching) ordered what I thought was the right cable (QBRCABFA-M[3] from sjs cycles). Turns out, it was the wrong one and the nipple is too small for my brake lever.

As described in this blog post:
http://blog.brilliantbikes.co.uk/2015/05/brompton-10-degree-brake-lever.html
... brompton move away from their own brake cables to a more standard type in 2012.

It seems the old cables are quite difficult to find now, the front cable I purchased was the only one I could find that looked right. One option might be to buy [this cable](https://www.sjscycles.co.uk/cables/brompton-brake-cable-assembly-rear-m-type-reversed-lwb-for-10-deg-lever/) for the rear brake, and cut the cable to the right length for the front...

So, my question is, how can I get round this without buying new brake levers? Anyone have any other bright ideas?

(Pic below shows my brake lever)

[image]

Comment: I think you're talking about the cable end, not the nipple.  The nipple is on the end of the cable housing.

Comment: Go to a shop that sells Brompton and get the cable from them?

Comment: Brake cables are consumables and eventually need replacing.  If you convert to standard brake levers then normal standard brake cables will work.  Of course, the cost different may make this a multi-decade payback window.

Comment: @Batman the correct cables are discontinued, and seem to be very difficult to find...

Answer (score 3):

Your own posted link says

> Brompton with the 10 degree brake levers with an open clevis should be
>   replaced with either the 30 degree or new aluminium brake levers.

Sounds like the 10 degree ones risk the cable's mushroom falling out of the open clevis, rendering the brake inoperable.  That would be bad.

You should replace the levers with safer ones.

Comment: Just a note to add that new brake levers are cheap (especially if you don't buy Brompton branded ones).  A new set can be had for less than 30 dollars/euro.

Comment: @RoboKaren agreed - for safety's sake alone I'd replace the brake levers and be done with it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Criggie. I had seen the advice to upgrade the brake levers, but was trying keep spending to an absolute minimum as I'll probably be selling the bike early next year... Maybe I'll just have to do the right thing and get some new levers!